# .NET Core TestServer returning 404 when using Startup class defined in unit test project

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-2.1

I've a basic .net core api web app and a unit test project that uses a TestServer to make http requests.

I've a TestStartup class that subclassed the Startup class in the api project.

If the Startup class is in the unit test project i get a 404 response.
If the TestStartup class is moved to the api project i get a 200 reponse.

Api Project

Api.csproj

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvcCore();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

TestController.cs

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("test")]
    public ObjectResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("data");
    }
}
```

Unit Test Project

Tests.csproj

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing" Version="2.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.10.1" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.10.0" />
```

Tests.cs

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        var server = new TestServer(WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseStartup<TestStartup>()
            .UseEnvironment("Development"));

        var response = await server.CreateClient().GetAsync("test");
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class TestStartup : Startup
{ }
```

Comment: I have just asked this question: stackoverflow.com/questions/53681935/… (before seeing yours). Did you find an answer? Could you answer my question? Thanks

Comment: I didn't find an answer. I rebuilt it from scratch and it worked. As far as I was concerned the implementations were exactly the same - one worked - the other didn't. There must have been something different - couldn't see what though.

Comment: not sure if this is the fix https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4332

Answer (score 58):

In case someone experiences this targeting ASP.NET Core **3.0** or **3.1**, don't forget to change the test project SDK to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`, i.e.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

as per [Test app prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#test-app-prerequisites).

Comment: Im having this exakt problem with net core 3.1 and I only have 'Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk' in my test project. I searched in Nuget for 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' but couldnt find it? How am I supposed to change the sdk?

Comment: No, you just need to edit the *.csproj file and change the first line there:
from: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
to: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
And then magic will happen ;)

Comment: This is like gold, no more like hens teeth.  Many thanks

Comment: Nice answer, it saved my day

Answer (score 13):

You could try two options below:

- Add `AddApplicationPart` to `Startup.cs`

  ```
  namespace IntegrationTestMVC
  {
  public class Startup
  {         

      // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {   
         services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("IntegrationTestMVC"))); //"IntegrationTestMVC" is your original project name
      }
  ```
- Try to convert `TestFixture` to `IClassFixture`

  ```
      public class IntegrationTestMVCUnitTest : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<TestStartup>>
  {
      private readonly HttpClient _client;
      private readonly WebApplicationFactory<TestStartup> _factory;

      public IntegrationTestMVCUnitTest(WebApplicationFactory<TestStartup> factory)
      {

          _factory = factory;
          _client = factory.CreateClient();
      }

      [Fact]
      public async Task IndexRendersCorrectTitle()
      {
          var response = await _client.GetAsync(@"/test");
      }

  }
  ```

For the second option, you could refer [Integration tests in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Was this the solution to the original question?

Comment: `services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(typeof(Startup).Assembly)`

Comment: What if dont use AddMvc?

Answer (score 6):

Adding a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` to the project file containing the test, as per the instructions in [aspnetcore-2.2#test-app-prerequisities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#test-app-prerequisites) fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update my nuget packages in test project to work