# How do I make my C# Test Server throw an exception on purpose?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I have an ErrorHandlingMiddleware class that is used across several projects and therefore lives in a shared library (and not in an API), and I want to write some tests for it. I have written a passing test using a TestServer (as described in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/middleware?view=aspnetcore-7.0)) that proves my middleware works when no exception is thrown by the endpoint, but am having trouble working out how to throw an exception on purpose in order to trigger the error handling part.

The only thing I've managed to find on this is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514422/configure-aspnetcore-testserver-to-return-500-instead-of-throwing-exception) which kinda does the literal opposite to what I want.

Here is my middleware code - ErrorHandlingService here is the thing that's just dealing with and formatting all my errors nicely.

```
        public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IErrorHandlingService errHandler)
        {
            _next = next;
            _errHandler = errHandler;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IHostEnvironment env)
        {
            try
            {
                _errHandler.AddRequestInformation(Guid.NewGuid(), DateTime.Now, $"{context.Request.Method} {context.Request.Path}");

                await _next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _errHandler.AddError(new MyError()
                {
                    Title = "An unknown error occurred during execution",
                    ErrorID = "---",
                    ErrorMessage = env.IsProduction() ? "" : ex.ToString(),
                    HttpCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
                });

                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)_errHandler.ErrorResponse.StatusCode;

                await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(_errHandler.ErrorResponse);
            }
        }
```

And my passing test that tests for *no* exception being thrown.

```
    public class ErrorHandlingMiddlewareTests
    {
        private async Task<IHost> GetHost()
        {
            return await new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureWebHost(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder
                        .UseTestServer()
                        .ConfigureServices(services =>
                        {
                            services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IErrorHandlingService, ErrorHandlingService>());
                        })
                        .Configure(app =>
                        {
                            app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
                        });
                })
                .StartAsync();
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task NewRequest_AddsRequestInformation()
        {
            // Arrange
            using var host = await GetHost();
            var requestRoute = "/route/to/endpoint";

            var server = host.GetTestServer();
            server.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://example.com/");

            // Act
            var context = await server.SendAsync(c => //throws a 404, I'm not testing for that
            {
                c.Request.Method = HttpMethods.Get;
                c.Request.Path = requestRoute;
            });

            // Assert
            var errorResponse = host.Services.GetService<IErrorHandlingService>().ErrorResponse;
            errorResponse.ErrorContent.Request.Should().Be("GET " + requestRoute);
            errorResponse.ErrorContent.TraceID.Should().NotBeEmpty();
        }
    }
```

So how do I now get the test server to throw an exception that can be caught by my middleware?

Comment: Seems to me you might want to create a sample web app specifically for testing, and use a test server around that application. You could have an endpoint specifically designed to throw an exception, or you could have a general-purpose endpoint that calls into a service which you could mock to produce different behaviors for each of your tests. See https://scotthannen.org/blog/2021/11/18/testserver-how-did-i-not-know.html

Comment: You might want to write unit tests instead. Simply have the mock throw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so less than 24 hours later I solved it <s>turns out as usual I just needed to sleep on it</s>. [StriplingWarrior's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75890793/how-do-i-make-my-c-sharp-test-server-throw-an-exception-on-purpose/75890908#comment133860926_75890793) pointed me towards a [guide](https://scotthannen.org/blog/2021/11/18/testserver-how-did-i-not-know.html) that, while not saying anything I didn't already know, did prompt me to think about how an app is actually built in .NET and where a normal API would go looking for controllers/routes.

Long story short after some trial and error and some research on how Startup.cs works and some [routing basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0) here's how I've solved it:

```
        private async Task<IHost> GetHost()
        {
            return await new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureWebHost(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder
                        .UseTestServer()
                        .ConfigureServices(services =>
                        {
                            services.AddRouting(); // <- new line
                            services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IErrorHandlingService, ErrorHandlingService>());
                        })
                        .Configure(app =>
                        {
                            app.UseRouting(); // <- new line
                            app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
                            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => // <- new section
                            {
                                endpoints.MapGet("/hello", () => "Hello World!");
                                endpoints.MapGet("/err", () => { throw new Exception(); });
                            });
                        });
                })
                .StartAsync();
        }
```

Using some inline definitions of new endpoints means I can easily control what's going in and out and could potentially make the responses more complex if I needed to. I guess it's pretty rare that you're testing stuff in a class library with a local TestServer but I hope this is helpful to the next person who doesn't have a Startup class to use.

Answer (score -2):

One way is to overload the handler with a flag and wrap it in DEBUG so it isn't in production builds. In tests where you want the error response, send true as a third parameter.

```
#if DEBUG
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IHostEnvironment env, isErrorTest)
{
  if (isErrorTest)
  {
    // Either build and respond with your error here, or possibly set something up on the server that would cause the normal handler to throw the error you want
    _errHandler.AddError(new MyError()
    {
      // ...
    });
    // ... error response
  }

  // if not error test, call your normal handler
}
#endif
```

Comment: This is a prime example of "test-induced damage": the middleware code and API shouldn't need to be polluted with knowledge of the tests that are being executed on it.